# AppCompatActivity has changed my AlertDialog design

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I have change my activity to appCompat Activity.
Also i changed AlertDialog to Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.
But i have lost my previous alertdialog design.
This is how it was look like.

[image]

And this is how it looks now
[image]
My theme till now was

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

But i was enforced to changed it cause appCompat doesn't support Holo theme.
So i change it to

```
 parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

How can i make alert dialog look like previous one?

Comment: The style you're seeing is indeed the correct Material style you'd expect when using AppCompat. You shouldn't be using the old holo themed dialog style.

Comment: The old holo themed dialog was deprecated long back, it's better not to use it anymore

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I am using it cause it has big buttons, and help user for easier press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

AlertDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog));

Comment: Thank you it works. But it also said that is obolete: deprecated.

Comment: Is there something Similar?

Comment: I'd suggest you build a dialog with custom buttons and stuff.Give it a little touch of your imagination ;)

Basically design the layout of dialog in xml and then inflate that and assign it to Alert Dialog. 
Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353260/10243423  
--
or you could use libraries
1) https://github.com/PatilShreyas/MaterialDialog-Android 
2) https://github.com/Shashank02051997/FancyAlertDialog-Android

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make buttons could help user for easier press, you can build a dialog with custom buttons and style the Button(e.g.style the Button on drawable folder).You can refer to the following code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
        alert.SetTitle("Login Information");
        //alert.SetMessage("Complex Alert");
        //alert.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.input_layout, null);
        alert.SetView(view);

        EditText editText_name = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_name);
        EditText editText_pwd = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_pwd);

        Button button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        Button button2 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);

        button1.Click += delegate {

            Toast.MakeText(this,"press button1!",ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        button2.Click += delegate {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "press button2!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        //alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
        //{
        //    // Ok button click task  
        //    string name = editText_name.Text;
        //    string password = editText_pwd.Text;
        //    Toast.MakeText(this, "name = " + name + " password= " + password, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        //});
        //alert.SetButton2("CANCEL", (c, ev) => { });
        alert.Show();
```

The `input_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/et_name"
  android:hint="please input name"
/>
<EditText 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
  android:password="true"
  android:hint="please input password"
/>

<LinearLayout 
   android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:text="button1"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/defaultbutton"
    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="button2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/defaultbutton"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

define a xml(e.g. `defaultbutton.xml`) in folder `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#1E90FF" />
<!--<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />-->
<corners
  android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
  android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

**Note:**

1.define a xml( `defaultbutton.xml`) in folder `drawable`

2.use like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/defaultbutton"
```

The result is：

[image]